# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154):

Tags: c#, exception

I'm getting an exception in a c# project:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {877AA945-1CB2-411C-ACD7-C70B1F9E2E32} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

What could it mean?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It means the class id 877AA945-1CB2-411C-ACD7-C70B1F9E2E32 is not in the registry.

You can verify this by opening regedit.exe, browsing to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{877AA945-1CB2-411C-ACD7-C70B1F9E2E32}`.  If your running a 32-bit app on a 64 bit OS, look for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{877AA945-1CB2-411C-ACD7-C70B1F9E2E32}`

If it is there, it may be some other issue but it is probably missing.  To resolve this you will usually run the installer that distributes this COM object.  If you don't have one and you know what dll implements the object, you can run regsvr32.exe (or regasm.exe for a managed dll).

Comment: Thanks, knowing that's a registry entry to look for really helped me track down the dll! I'm new to windows programming so had no idea where to look :)

Comment: this answer help me to resolve a similar problem

Comment: I helped to resolve my problem.

Comment: I have facing same issue and checked HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{9DFF2B08-C9EC-11D4-9191-0010A4E6EB31} but this key is not there so what should I do now?

Comment: @Naveen register the  COM object dll

Comment: I am trying to register it using regsvr32 but getting error **The module was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.**

Comment: This helped me to resolve similar issues

Answer (score 8):

I was running a C++ COM DLL from a Win Forms C# project on a 64-bit OS. I changed the Win Forms C# project to be x86, re-ran, and it worked.  To do this:-

1. Right-click the .NET project, and choose *Properties*
2. Select the **Build** tab
3. Set *Platform target* to `x86`
4. Recompile, and re-run

Concept of changing bitness from [George J's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44646772/3063884)

Answer (score 1):

I am running some automated tests in Selenium and had same problem. Problem was solved by switching "Default Processor Architecture" to x86 in Test Settings.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the Class was registered properly.

But the **Enable 32-bit Applications** property of the **IIS Application pool** of the Application which uses the class was set to **True**. It was not finding it because the application was built in ANY CPU / 64 bit mode.

Setting **Enable 32-bit Applications** to **False** fixed the issue.