# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4C2901D1-5354-11D4-A6F9-00508B4ACA2C} failed due to the following error: 80040154

Tags: vb.net, windows, dll, com, exe

I was trying to execute an executable, but got error message:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4C2901D1-5354-11D4-A6F9-00508B4ACA2C} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

this exe comes along with 4 dll files in its own folder:

- ATTPRV32.dll
- Csta32.dll
- Interop.AXS_INPROCLib.dll
- Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll

I've tried to register each of these dll files but got the same error message:

> .DLL was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found

Comment: Stack Overflow is about programming problems. Is your executable something you've written? Can you tell us more about it?

Answer (score 0):

It means the class: 4C2901D1-5354-11D4-A6F9-00508B4ACA2C isnt in the registry plain and simple.

See more here...

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663994/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-0x80040154)

Comment: I used this method to registerred 2 dll files of the 4 successfully, but the error message remains the same...

Comment: BTW, I can find this entry in registry after regasm it