# A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.Synchronization.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, microsoft-sync-framework, hresult

Im developing with Microsoft Sync 2.1 SDK
When I try to synch from my Hard Drive to an external Hard Drive (Toshiba 1,5 Gb) I have this problem:
From my develop enviroment (Personal Computer)

A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.Synchronization.dll
From my laptop (Other Computer)

Retriving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {....} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

I read a lot of entries in this web( for example: [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663994/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-0x80040154?s=8|2.1490))
Explaining the problem, my problem isnt with platform (x32/x64) my problem is related with the registering but I don't know how to register in the computer or run "regsvr32.exe dll"
How can I obtain the COM object of my hard drive?
If I would like to user others External Hard Drives, is necessary install all the drivers of all the drivers?

I attach you all the error messages:

```
SyncException Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal



SyncException Message:



SyncException InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80041007)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.CoreInterop.ISyncSession.Start(CONFLICT_RESOLUTION_POLICY resolutionPolicy, _SYNC_SESSION_STATISTICS& pSyncSessionStatistics)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeSyncOrchestrator.DoOneWaySyncHelper(SyncIdFormatGroup sourceIdFormats, SyncIdFormatGroup destinationIdFormats, KnowledgeSyncProviderConfiguration destinationConfiguration, SyncCallbacks DestinationCallbacks, ISyncProvider sourceProxy, ISyncProvider destinationProxy, ChangeDataAdapter callbackChangeDataAdapter, SyncDataConverter conflictDataConverter, Int32& changesApplied, Int32& changesFailed)

SyncException HelpLink: 

SyncException Source: Microsoft.Synchronization

SyncException StackTrace:    at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeSyncOrchestrator.DoOneWaySyncHelper(SyncIdFormatGroup sourceIdFormats, SyncIdFormatGroup destinationIdFormats, KnowledgeSyncProviderConfiguration destinationConfiguration, SyncCallbacks DestinationCallbacks, ISyncProvider sourceProxy, ISyncProvider destinationProxy, ChangeDataAdapter callbackChangeDataAdapter, SyncDataConverter conflictDataConverter, Int32& changesApplied, Int32& changesFailed)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeSyncOrchestrator.DoOneWayKnowledgeSync(SyncDataConverter sourceConverter, SyncDataConverter destinationConverter, SyncProvider sourceProvider, SyncProvider destinationProvider, Int32& changesApplied, Int32& changesFailed)
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeSyncOrchestrator.Synchronize()
   at Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncOrchestrator.Synchronize()
   at Eric.Form1.Synchronize(String source, String destination)

SyncException TargetSite: Void DoOneWaySyncHelper(Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncIdFormatGroup, Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncIdFormatGroup, `enter codehere`Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeSyncProviderConfiguration, Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncCallbacks, ISyncProvider, ISyncProvider, Microsoft.Synchronization.ChangeDataAdapter, Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncDataConverter, Int32 ByRef, Int32 ByRef)
```

Thanks for your help!
Frank

Comment: The error in the snippet is SYNC_E_ITEM_MUST_EXIST, "A synchronization provider reports that an item does not exist in its replica, although the creation version of the item is contained in the knowledge from that provider".  The error you are talking about is something *completely* different, it suggests that the machine does not have Windows Sync installed or your program is running in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed Sync Fx properly, you don't have to do regsvr for the DLLs. the error is mostly due to the target platform of the application not matching the platform of Sync Fx installed. (you cant have the exe target x64 and install x86 Sync Fx). you need to install Sync Fx on the machine running the sync, not on the external drive